# Warning - Certain functionality requires requests_html, which is not installed

Tags: django, python-requests-html

when I run my django server everything works fine. However right before the normal prompt that comes from running the server, I get this message

```
Warning - Certain functionality
             requires requests_html, which is not installed.

             Install using:
             pip install requests_html

             After installation, you may have to restart your Python session.
Warning - Certain functionality
             requires requests_html, which is not installed.

             Install using:
             pip install requests_html

             After installation, you may have to restart your Python session.
```

And then my django server goes on and runs fine. I'm worried that when I deploy my website this error will be a problem. Btw I know where this is coming from. I'm using yahoo_fin and requests_html is a dependency, however I'm not using and won't use the yahoo_fin methods that require this dependency, so I guess what I'm asking is for a way to ignore this random Warning.

I've tried installing the `requests_html` library but I still get the same error, even after I restart my Python session like the message says.

Comment: Hi there, I am not clear whether are using `yahoo_fin` in your project or not however if you are using `yahoo_fin` then you must install the dependencies ( `request_html`) and if you are not using `yahoo_fin` uninstall it directly. Even if you install the `request_html` and still get that error then try to restart the server.

Comment: Hey, yeah I am using ```yahoo_fin```. I've tried installing requests_html and restarting the server, but I still get the same error. I uninstall and reinstall and it still pops up. I've also tried deleting my virtual env and making a new one, but that also doesn't work. Is there a way to simply handle this Warning message as if it were an error? It doesn't throw any errors, so I wouldn't be sure how to do this, but it's an idea. I looked at the ```yahoo_fin``` documentation and know for sure that I won't need the methods that utilize the ```requests_html``` library.

Comment: I got the same thing with randomly and not sure why, `requests_html` is indeed installed and working for me as well

Comment: try to import `requests_html` and see if you get any errors